# How to return enum from property in enum

Tags: python, enums, properties, getter

I have an enum with a set as value for the items. In a property method I would like to return an intersection of the previous chained enum. But the result type of the property should be the same enum class.

Given this abstract example

```py
from enum import Enum


class Letters(Enum):
    abc = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

    @property
    def a(self):
        """ Returns a subset of a Letters Enum """
        letter = {'a'}
        return letter.intersection(self.value)
```

The type of an Item is an enum of `Letters`, which is correct

```py
print(type(Letters.abc))
# prints <enum 'Letters'>
```

But when I call the property of the resulting enum, it is of type `set`

```
print(type(Letters.abc.a))
# prints <class 'set'>
# I want this to be <enum 'Letters'> instead
```

How can I change the code so that the property returns a value of type enum?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the code so that the property returns a value of type enum?

Using 'Enum', the only way would be to having members for all possible combinations:

```
class Letters(Enum):
    abc = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
    a = {'a'}
    ab = {'ab'}
    ac = {'ac'}
    # etc.
```

and then return the correct member in the property:

```
return self.__class__(letter.intersection(self.value))
```